# What is the plural of "Freight"?

Tags: grammatical-number

What is the plural of *freight*? *Freights* just doesn't sound right to me. Perhaps, *freight* is already the plural. If that is the case, what is its singular?

**Edit**

After doing some research, most online dictionaries have *freights* as part of their listing for *freight*, but none seem to have an example, leading me to the conclusion that *freights* is not a word that is in common use.  The definition provided by Brian Hooper seemed to be the  most reasonable and clear reason why it is only *freight*

Comment: "What is the plural of" questions can be answered with any good dictionary. If you still have confusion about the plural after looking it up, edit your question to show what you found and explain why you are still confused.

Comment: @MetaEd I understand.  I had done some research but was confused by what I found as there seemed to be conflicting results. I wanted to  understand the reasoning behind the definition.

Comment: Good edit. Nominating to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Freight](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/freight)*:-

> 1. Goods carried by a vessel or vehicle, especially by a commercial carrier; cargo.
> 2. A burden; a load.
> 3. a. Commercial transportation of goods. b. The charge for transporting goods. Also called freightage.
> 4. A railway train carrying goods only.

is normally a *[non-count noun](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/non-count+noun)*:-

> a noun, as water, electricity,  or happiness,  that typically refers
>   to an indefinitely divisible substance or an abstract notion, and that
>   in English cannot be used, in such a sense, with the indefinite
>   article or in the plural.

so the question doesn't arise; you can't point at a heap of goods and say *there are thirteen freights here*; it would be *some freight* or *100 tons of freight*.

In the specialist meaning (4) above, short for a *freight train*, one could count them (*eleven freights ran past my house last night*) and then the plural would be *freights*.

Comment: I think that the non-count noun is what tripped me up. thanks :-)

Comment: Meaning #4 is not used in BrE: we'd say "freight train". It's not given in [Chambers](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=freight&title=21st) as a noun, and [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/freight?q=freight)  lists it as a *noun* only in its [US definition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/freight).